# Is there a way to associate an individual file with a specific application

Tags: file

I mean a specific file not a file extension

Answer (score 1):

[FileAssociation](http://www.mentalis.org/soft/class.qpx?id=5) might help you here.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about windows operating system, then answer is **no**.You can only associate an application with specific extension.but there is an **alternative solution** to it that you may develop an **launcher application**, which will get associated with that extension and based on file provided to it by argument launcher application will decide which application will be launched to open that file.